# How to remove whitespace between a <td> tag until the string?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a string

```
<td>    Some text</td><td>  July 3, 2013</td>
```

I want to remove the leading spaces so the resulting string looks like

```
<td>Some text</td><td>July 3, 2013</td>
```

I am playing around with preg_replace, but can't seem to figure out the proper syntax.

```
preg_replace('/<td>\s+/', '<td>', $strip2); **<-doesn't work**
```

Comment: Do you have to use PHP? Or can you use jQuery?

Comment: Yes I have to use PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp works perfectly:

```
<?php
$str = "<td>    Some text</td><td>  July 3, 2013</td>";
$str = preg_replace('/<td>\s+/', '<td>', $str);
print $str;
```

prints:

```
<td>Some text</td><td>July 3, 2013</td>
```

Comment: Never thought to try it out on it's own :-$. This bit of code is mixed in with a bunch of other regexpr...I guess something else is changing it later. On the positive side...I can stop trying to figure this piece out. I have a sneaky suspision that it could be this next line: `$chars = preg_split('/<[^>]*[^\/]>/i', $strip3, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);`

Comment: OK, the problem is that my string has hidden characters that I can't seem to get rid of. `<td>   April 14, 2011</td>` displayed in a print statement has leading `Â Â Â`. I've tried a bunch of different things like `preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string)` to remove all hidden characters, but no luck???

Comment: @mlav It was not clear from your question, that you had hidden characters. Glad, that you removed them. Any more problems with this string?

Comment: I didn't know I had hidden chars until the end...they only appeared after I started testing smaller bits of my code on the console after you confirmed my initial code worked. No more problem, thanks @user4035

Answer (score -1):

Finally found the piece of code i needed to clean up my string

```
preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/', '', $strip2);
```